# How to set the height of the images in the list by the smallest height of image in angular js?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am currently studying angular js and i have a problem in setting the height of the images by the smallest height in the div... By the way, I am using ng-repeat in li. This is my code:

```
app.directive("cardListStyle01",function(){
    return {
        template: `
            <li class='contentContainer02 card' ng-repeat='d in data'>
                <div class='imageBlock'>
                    <div class='logo'><img src='/images/img0{{$index%5+1}}.jpg' alt=''></div>
                    <h3 class='cardTitle cWhite'>{{d.name}}</h3>
                </div>
                <div class='cardContentBlock'>
                    <p class='cardPar'>{{d.employeeNum}}</p>
                </div>
            </li>
        `
    }
})
```

What i want is for example:

> img1 height = 200px.
>       img2 height = 100px.
>       img3 height = 90px.
>       img4 height = 260px.
>       img5 height = 120px.

after running the code, the img height will become 90

> img1 height = 90px img2 height = 90px img3 height = 90px img4 height =
>   90px img5 height = 90px

how can I do that?
Also, how to select element in angular js like selecting element in jquery?
Thank you for your response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This selects all items with the class '.my-image'.

```
var images = document.querySelectorAll('.my-image');
```

Then find a minimum:

```
var minHeight = images[0].offsetHeight;
images.forEach(function(item){
    minHeight = Math.min(minHeight, item.offsetHeight)
})
```

Then just set the height to all elements:

```
images.forEach(function(item){
    angular.element(item).css({ 
        height: minHeight + 'px' 
    });
})
```

If it isn't working use $timeout to perform these manipulations after html is loaded:

```
$timeout({
    // all the code above
})
```

Comment: where shoud i put this code? in controller or in directive?

Comment: In controller, usually

Comment: I try this selector but its not working. var images = angular.element(document.querySelector('.card img'));Did I do something wrong?

Comment: A class name should not contain whitespaces.

Comment: Please, change '.card img' to '.card-img'. Everywhere

Comment: Its not working. TypeError: Cannot read property 'offsetHeight' of undefined

Comment: Did you change the class name in html too?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151457/discussion-between-jemuel-elimanco-and-maxwellt).

Comment: yes
<div class='logo'><img class = 'card-img' src='/images/img0{{$index%5+1}}.jpg' alt=''></div>